# How to make Google Photos recognise 360 photos (e.g. from DJI Mini 2)

Tags: metadata, exif, dji-sdk, google-photos

Google photos provides a really nice way of viewing 360 photos from a mobile device, where you can look around the photo by moving the phone.

For example, here is a 360 photos from my Parrot ANAFI drone:
https://photos.app.goo.gl/Pj2HUYyN9FaajWhg7

For some reason, Google Photos doesn't recognise my 360 photos from my DJI Mini 2 as being 360.  Rather it just sees them as being one big flat image. e.g.
https://photos.app.goo.gl/o9B6KYQMUBRGT7vp8

Where when viewing from a phone, you get this option to navigate around the image using the phone.

I can't find good clear documentation on how Google Photos recognises 360 photos.

Any solution (including programatically editing image metadata) is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Found one approach that works - the [Meta360 App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hirota41.photospheretaggerpro&hl=en_US&gl=US) on Google Play.  You share the original 360 photo to the app, then the app saves a copy with the right metadata, then you re-upload to google photos.